# Isabelle HOLCF doesn't understand fixrec

Tags: isabelle

Here is a very simple theory:

```
theory Test
  imports HOLCF
begin
  fixrec down :: "'a u → 'a"
    where "down (up x) = x"
end
```

It gives the following error:

```
Type unification failed: Clash of types "_ ⇒ _" and "_ → _"

Type error in application: operator not of function type

Operator:  up :: ??'a → ??'a⇩⊥
Operand:   x :: ??'b
```

I have tried to declare different functions but I always get a similar error. What's a problem and how to fix it?

I tried to replace → by ⇒, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single arrow `→` is the space of continuous functions whereas the double arrow `⇒` represents the space of all total functions. All packages in `HOLCF` only work with continuous functions. This is why `⇒` will not work for most of `HOLCF`. Function application for continuous functions, however, must be written explicitly using the ASCII infix operator `$` or `\<cdot>`. So the following works:

```
fixrec down :: "'a u → 'a"
  where "down $ (up $ x) = x"
```

Similarly, lambda abstractions for continuous functions use a capital `Λ` instead of a small `λ`.